# How to web scrape information online and extract it as an excel file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some information of music top list from a online website. I would like to have all the ranking, artists and the songs as a data list.
https://www.joox.com/hk/chart/1

Here is my code to scrape:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.joox.com/hk/chart/1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
all_songs = soup.find_all(class_="jsx-2493651356")
print(all_songs)
```

And the output:

```
[<b class="jsx-2493651356 SongName"><a class="jsx-2493651356" href="/hk/single/rZ73LAjIW3eVn3zL4Oy0TA==">再見 寧靜海</a><span class="jsx-2493651356"></span></b>, <a class="jsx-2493651356" href="/hk/single/rZ73LAjIW3eVn3zL4Oy0TA==">再見 寧靜海</a>, <span class="jsx-2493651356"></span>, <b class="jsx-2493651356 SongName"><a class="jsx-2493651356" href="/hk/single/F12EPIkv3Yc03x2Rlpz_kA==">世一</a><span class="jsx-2493651356"></span></b>, <a class="jsx-2493651356" href="/hk/single/F12EPIkv3Yc03x2Rlpz_kA==">世一</a>, <span class="jsx-2493651356"></span>, <b class="jsx-2493651356 SongName"><a class="jsx-2493651356" href="/hk/single/0MOttR+8yWzPqsuwrCn7wg==">LOVERSE</a><span class="jsx-2493651356"></span></b>
...
```

The output is very messy and some of the information are duplicated.

How to find all the specific information that I've motioned above and store them into a data list but not duplicated?

I'm trying to get a expected result like the following result:

```
Ranking        Artist          Song
1              Ian 陳卓賢       再見 寧靜海
2              MC 張天賦        世一
3....
...
```

and save it as an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

names = [name.get_text() for name in soup.select(".SongName a")]
artists = [artist.get_text() for artist in soup.select(".SongDescItem a")]

rank = 1
data = []
for name, artist in zip(names, artists):
    data.append({
        "Ranking": rank,
        "Song": name,
        "Artist": artist,
    })
    rank += 1

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

This should do the trick.
Since the website is geo-locked in my region, this is a general outline, you can play with the CSS selectors in case the above don't work out.

Comment: It seems fine, but the output becomes gibberish.```1 ?? 撖折?瘚?Ian ?喳?鞈? 
2 銝? MC 撘萄予鞈?
3 LOVERSE Edan ?摰?
4 ?臬??潛 閮勗遠??Alfred Hui
5 ?脣??? ?喳?餈?
6 ?啣??潛???暻潔? Dear Jane
```

Comment: Not sure what you meant by gibberish, the characters themselves due to encoding or the CSV structure?